# HTML Form: Input type hidden value is visible and changable - Recording Processed State

Tags: php, html, forms, post, session-variables

I am working on an application that I need to post a secret variable. I wrote this code.

```
<form target="_blank" action="/validate/lista.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="evento" value="<?php echo $pname ?>" />
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-outline-success">Lista</button>
</form>
```

My problem is that if the user inspect the element with chrome or whatever, he can see the value and change it before POST.
I could use SESSION but every user has a different session ID and this way I would need to POST the session ID (because they are separete applications), which I think is not secure. Or is it ok?

How can I prevent this? I am new to programming...

Thank you

Comment: _everything_ you send to the client can be seen by the user. No matter if you hide it in an element, in a js, in a cookie, ...

Comment: What is the value/purpose of this "secret variable"?

Comment: it is a login variable, not password, but let's assume it as a global username that I do not want everyone to know. It is used to connect to a database

Comment: So why are you sending it to the front-end at all?  Sounds like something that should maybe be in a config file or something.

Comment: because the database name is bound to this variable. The end-user need to connect to this database without knowing its name. Only the user that created it should know

Comment: I think you need to start at the beginning with what's really going on here.  Where are you _getting_ this value that you're currently passing to the front-end form?  If you can get this value when the page is generated, aren't you also able to get it when the page is submitted, without actually passing it back and forth?

Comment: but how can I post a variable without storing it in a input when the page is generated?

Comment: The point is that you likely _don't need to_ be posting the variable.  Simply have `/validate/lista.php` fetch the value directly, the same way the form page is.

Comment: Well, that's a point. It would need much more programming, since I would need to request even more information, non sensitive, and connect to other databases. but yes, I could do that. The point is, is there any way to hide the values of a post variable? or at least make it  harder to find other than simply inspecting the element?

Comment: just thoughts: My answer to this issue is to have a 'state vector' (an array) for a form. it has: a unique id for the form, a timestamp, then any fields i want to come back with the form. user id, etc, this is the fun part.. I serialize and encrypt it :) that gets put in the hidden field. :)  when the form comes back I decrypt it and process the form. :) I store the unique form id in a 'processed forms' list :) This can be used to stop all the nonsense that people try to do with forms :) Only the server needs to know the password :)

Comment: @RyanVincent That still doesn't address the fact that you're sending that value in a request and therefore it can be whatever the end-user wants it to be. While it may be less likely for the user to send a different _usable_ value, if this value is really representing a table or database name in a query, it could still produce quite bad results.

Comment: The fact that it's encrypted just means that, like I said, the user is less likely to pass another _meaningful_ value.  That does _not_ mean that they can't _change_ it.  It's still being sent just like any other request value.  The user can still change it to 'bob' if they want.  Depending on what they enter, this could lead to quite unexpected results when you go to use the "decrypted" value as a database name in a query.

Comment: The cannot change the user id in the encrypted field can they? The whole 'form state vector' is just an encrypted string in the hidden field. The don't know the password to it. If the try and change it then they destroy it and the form will fail. If you encrypt the 'evento' value with a password only you know then the client cannot change it?

Comment: I had this idea of encrypting it but thought I was overthinking it haha... I just didnt get well how did you work with the timestamp. Would you provide this as an answer? No need for encryption code though. This is another story.

Comment: Yes, the timestamp and the unique form id allow you to control duplicate processing due to form resubmission and forms being out of date. I could do an answer. I will put some thoughts and sample code. Will be a while - should be available  tomorrow.

Comment: Nice!! Looking forward for this, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Maintain HTML Form State safely ('Conversation' Tracking)

Keep track of the 'state' of an HTML Form as it is processed by the client and the server.

The typical 'conversation' is:

1. Send a new form to the client, often for a specific user who has to login.
2. The client enters data and returns it.
3. It is validated and may be sent out again.
4. The data changes are applied.
5. the client is informed of the result.

It sounds simple. Alas, we need to keep track of the 'state' of the form during the 'conversation'.

We need to record the state in a hidden field. This can open us up to various 'failure modes'.

This answer is one method of reliably keeping track of the 'conversations'.

Including people being 'malicious'. It happens. ;-/

This is a data change form so we don't want it applied to the wrong person.

#### There are various requirements:

**Sensible ones:**

1. prevent a form being processed twice
2. Ask a user to confirm the data if the form is too old

**Malicious ones:**

1. Changing the form to appear to be from a different user
2. Using an old copy of the form
3. Changing other hidden data to corrupt the user data

Now, we cannot prevent the client changing the hidden data, or storing it to replay later. etc.

**What to do?**

1. We need to ensure that if it is changed then we can detect that it is tampered with and tell the user about it. We do nothing.
2. If they send us an old stored valid copy then we can detect that as well.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Oh yes! :)

**Answers:**

1. Give each form a unique id: makes it easy to determine if we have already seen it.
2. Give each form a timestamp of when it was first created.

we can then decide the max age we allow to use it.
If it is too old then we just copy the entered data to a new form and ask the user to confirm it. see Captcha :)

When we process the form we store the form id.

The first check before processing a form is to see if we have already processed it

**Identifying 'tampering'?**

We encrypt it with AES! :) Only the server needs to know the password so there are no client issues.

If it is changed then the decrypt will fail and we just issue a new form to the user with the data input on it. :)

Is it a lot of code? Not really. And it makes forms processing safe.

One advantage is that has the protection for the CSRF attack built in so no separate code needed.

#### Program Code (FormState Class)

```
<?php
/**
* every 'data edit' form has one of these - without exeception.
*
* This ensures that the form I sent out came from me. 
* 
* It has: 
*    1) A unique @id
*    2) A date time stamp and a lifetime
* 
*  Can be automatically generated and checked. 
*/

class FormState {

    const MAX_FORM_AGE = 600; // seconds 

    const ENC_PASSWORD = '327136823981d9e57652bba2acfdb1f2';   
    const ENC_IV       = 'f9928260b550dbb2eecb6e10fcf630ba';   

    protected $state = array();

    public function __construct($prevState = '')
    {
        if (!empty($prevState)) {
            $this->reloadState($prevState); // will not be valid if fails
            return;
        }

        $this->setNewForm();
    }

    /**
     * Generate a new unique id and timestanp
     *
     * @param $name - optional name for the form
     */
    public function setNewForm($name = '')
    {
        $this->state = array();
        $this->state['formid'] = sha1(uniqid(true)); // each form has a unique id 
        $this->state['when'] = time();

        if (!empty($name)) {
            $this->setAttribute('name', $name);
        }
    }

    /**
     * retrieve attribute value
     *
     * @param $name     attribute name to use
     * @param $default  value to return if attribute does not exist
     * 
     * @return string / number
     */
    public function getAttribute($name, $default = null) 
    {
            if (isset($this->state[$name])) {
                   return $this->state[$name];
            } else {
                   return $default;
            }   
    }

    /**
     * store attribute value
     *
     * @param $name     attribute name to use
     * @param $value    value to save
     */
    public function setAttribute($name, $value) 
    {
            $this->state[$name] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * get the array
     */
    public function getAllAttributes()
    {
        return $this->state;
    } 

    /**
     * the unique form id
     *  
     * @return hex string
     */
    public function getFormId()
    {
        return $this->getAttribute('formid');    
    }

    /**
     * Age of the form in seconds
     * @return int seconds
     */
    public function getAge()
    {
        if ($this->isValid()) {
            return time() - $this->state['when'];
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * check the age of the form
     * 
     *@param $ageSeconds is age older than the supplied age 
     */
    public function isOutOfDate($ageSeconds = self::MAX_FORM_AGE)
    {
        return $this->getAge() >= $ageSeconds;
    }

    /**
     * was a valid string passed when restoring it
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isValid()
    { 
        return is_array($this->state) && !empty($this->state);
    }

    /** -----------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Encode as string - these are encrypted to ensure they are not tampered with  
     */

    public function asString()
    {        
        $serialized = serialize($this->state);
        $encrypted = $this->encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $serialized);

        $result = base64_encode($encrypted);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Restore the saved attributes - it must be a valid string 
     *
     * @Param $prevState
     * @return array Attributes
     */
    public function fromString($prevState)
    {
        $encrypted = @base64_decode($prevState);
        if ($encrypted === false) {
           return false; 
        }

        $serialized = $this->encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $encrypted);
        if ($serialized === false) {
           return false; 
        }

        $object = @unserialize($serialized);
        if ($object === false) {
           return false; 
        }

        if (!is_array($object)) {
            throw new \Exception(__METHOD__ .' failed to return object: '. $object, 500);
        }
        return $object; 
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->asString();
    }

    /**
     * Restore the previous state of the form 
     *    will not be valid if not a valid string
     *
     * @param  $prevState  an encoded serialized array
     * @return bool isValid or not
     */
    public function reloadState($prevState)
    {
        $this->state = array();

        $state = $this->fromString($prevState);
        if ($state !== false) {
            $this->state = $state;
        }

        return $this->isValid();
    }

    /**
     * simple method to encrypt or decrypt a plain text string
     * initialization vector(IV) has to be the same when encrypting and decrypting
     * 
     * @param string $action: can be 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'
     * @param string $string: string to encrypt or decrypt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) 
    {
        $output = false;

        $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $secret_key = self::ENC_PASSWORD;


        // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
        $secret_iv_len = openssl_cipher_iv_length($encrypt_method);
        $secret_iv = substr(self::ENC_IV, 0, $secret_iv_len);

        if ( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
            $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $secret_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $secret_iv);

        } else if( $action == 'decrypt' ) {
            $output = openssl_decrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $secret_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $secret_iv);
        }

        if ($output === false) {
            // throw new \Exception($action .' failed: '. $string, 500);
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

#### Example Code

[Full Example Application Source Code (Q49924789)](http://ge.tt/2J9tmXp2)

[Website Using the supplied Source Code](http://ryanvincent.uk/formstate/)

[FormState source code](https://pastebin.com/fBD78GA8)

**Do we have an existing form?**

```
$isExistingForm = !empty($_POST['formState']);
$selectedAction = 'start-NewForm'; // default action

  if  ($isExistingForm) { // restore state  
    $selectedAction = $_POST['selectedAction'];      
    $formState = new \FormState($_POST['formState']); // it may be invalid
    if (!$formState->isValid() && $selectedAction !== 'start-NewForm') {
        $selectedAction = "formState-isWrong"; // force user to start a new form
    }

} else {
    $_POST = array();  // yes, $_POST is just another PHP array 
    $formState = new \FormState();    
}
```

**Start New Form**

```
    $formState = new \FormState();
    $_POST = array(); 
    $displayMsg = "New formstate created. FormId: ". $formState->getFormId();
```

**Store UserId (Database Id) in the FormState**

```
        $formState->setAttribute('userId' $userId);
```

**Check a form being to old?**

```
  $secsToBeOutOfDate = 3;

  if ($formState->isOutOfDate($secsToBeOutOfDate)) {
    $errorMsg = 'Out Of Date Age: '. $secsToBeOutOfDate .'secs'
                .', ActualAge: '. $formState->getAge();
  }
```

**Reload State from the form hidden field.**

```
  $formState = new \FormState('this is rubbish!!');
  $errorMsg = "formState: isValid(): ". ($formState->isValid() ? 'True' : 'False');
```

**Check if a form has already been processed.**

```
  if (isset($_SESSION['processedForms'][$formState->getFormId()])) {
      $errorMsg = 'This form has already been processed. (' . $formState->getFormId() .')';
      break;
  }

  $_SESSION['processedForms'][$formState->getFormId()]  = true;
  $displayMsg = "Form processed and added to list.";
```

Comment: That's perfect Ryan. I got your code yesterday, was studying it. Thank you!

Comment: I was thinking about changing the question title to:
Input type hidden value is visible and changable, prevent form edition before POST. 
What do you think about it? May be easier for people to find it